# React "this" undefined in method child async func

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-2017

I have a component, in which I define handleClick (onClick handler) and I want to call Async function. Code below what I did, my question: why 'this' is not accessible in Async function() call?

```
class GameListItem extends BaseComponent {
constructor(props, context) {
    super(props, context);
    this.state = {
        name: props.name,
        owner: props.owner,
        uid: props.uid,
        status: props.status
    };
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
}

handleClick() {
    let inst = this;
    (
        async function() {

            // WHY HERE 'this' is undefined?

            let res = await inst.engine.async_action({'action': 'join_game', 'data': {'game_uid': inst.state.uid}});
            console.log('res: ', res);
        }()
    );
}

render() {
    return (
        <li className="list-group-item" >
            <ProtectedLink text={this.state.name} classes="game_link" onClick={this.handleClick}/>
        </li>
    );
}
}
```

Comment: The function doesn't use `this`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. I lost context in IIFE. This works:

```
    (
        async function(inst) {
            let res = await inst.engine.async_action({'action': 'join_game', 'data': {'game_uid': inst.state.uid}});
            console.log('res: ', res);
        }
    )(this);
```